# How to modify already sent broadcast in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I'm using broadcast receiver in my SMS scheduling application. I want to modify that broadcast which has already been sent.
what should i do to edit or delete the already sent broadcast ?

Answer (score 2):

these links will help u. 
[BroadcostRecivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html),

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/an-android-coders-introduction-to-broadcast-receivers/1173

Answer (score 0):

I think already sent broadcast cannot be edited. you can resent the correct data .

Comment: i think, its possible because, in many scheduling applications , like in sms scheduling application, when we set a message to sent at specific time, then there is an option there to edit that action.

Comment: u say about the scheduling applications the message edited before the specific time (before sent that message) .After sending that message we can't change that message .u ask about  "I want to modify that broadcast which has already been sent"

Comment: I asked to edit the broadcast, i didn't ask about TEXT messages :) kindly, read question carefully.